# SMP affinity vs XPS on paired queues and TX queue selection control

Tags: networking, low-latency, affinity, smp

I have a solarflare nic with paired rx and tx queues (8 sets, 8 core machine real machine, not hyperthreading, running ubuntu) and each set shares an IRQ number. I have used smp_affinity to set which irqs are processed by which core. Does this ensure that the transmit (tx) interrupts are also handled by the same core. How will this work with xps?

For instance, lets say the irq# is 115, set to core 2 (via smp_affinity). Say the nic chooses tx-2 for outgoing tcp packets, which also happens to have 115 irq number. If I have an xps setting saying tx-2 should be accessible by cpu 4, then which one takes precedence - xps or smp_affinity?

Also is there a way to see/set which tx queue is being used for a particular app/tcp connection? I have an app that receives udp data, processes it and sends tcp packets, in a very latency sensitive environment. I wish to handle the tx interrupts on the outgoing on the same cpu (or one on the same numa node) as the app creating this traffic, however, I have no idea how to find which tx queue is being used by this app for this purpose. While the receive side has indirection tables to set up rules, I do not know if there is a way to set the tx-queue selection and therefore pin it to a set of dedicated cpus.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the application the preferred CPU by setting the cpu affinity (taskset) or numa node affinity, and you can also set the IRQ affinities (in /proc/irq/270/node, or by using the old intel script floating around 'set_irq_affinity.sh' which is on github). This won't completely guarantee which irq / cpu is being used, but it will give you a good head start on it. If all that fails, to improve latency you might want to enable packet steering in the rxqueue so you get the packets in quicker to the correct cpu (/sys/class/net//queues/rx-#/rps_cpus and tx-#/xps-cpus). There is also the irqbalance program and more....it is a broad subject and i am just learning much of it myself.